# trying to select precedent nodes using lxml xpath

Tags: python, xslt, xpath, lxml

I am trying to get preceding-sibling of current selected node but not sure what i am doing wrong .

This is the html snap :

```
source = """
    <div class="zg_itemImmersion">
    <div class="zg_rankDiv"><span class="zg_rankNumber">10.</span></div>
    <div class="zg_itemWrapper" style="height:285px">
       <div class="zg_image">
          <div class="zg_itemImageImmersion"><a  href="
             http://www.amazon.com/Oral-B-Action-Replacement-Electric-Toothbrush/dp/B000AUIFCA/ref=zg_mw_8517148011_10"><img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41RHKIQXnhL._SL160_SL150_.jpg" alt="Oral-B Floss Action Replacement Elect..." title="Oral-B Floss Action Replacement Elect..."/></a></div>
       </div>
    </div>
"""
```

What i am trying to get is rankNumber if href contains ASIN : B000AUIFCA,

```
from lxml import html 
source1 = html.fromstring(source)
links = source1.xpath('//div[@class="zg_itemImmersion"]//div[@class="zg_itemImageImmersion"]/a[contains(@href,"B000AUIFCA")]/@href')
```

The above gives me the right link that contains my needed ASIN : B000AUIFCA

```
['\n\n\n\n\n\n\nhttp://www.amazon.com/Oral-B-Action-Replacement-Electric-Toothbrush/dp/B000AUIFCA/ref=zg_mw_8517148011_10/191-4138574-0525467']
```

Now i want to have the rank "10" from preceeding-sibling - `[span class="zg_rankNumber"]` if ASIN in `('//span[@class="zg_rankNumber"]//a//@href')` == B000AUIFCA

for that i am using : `link2 = source1.xpath('//div[@class="zg_itemImmersion"]//div[@class="zg_itemImageImmersion"]/a[contains(@href,"B000AUIFCA")]/preceding-sibling::*/text()')`

but its returning Null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following XPath :

```
//div[@class="zg_itemImmersion"]
     [.//div[@class="zg_itemImageImmersion"]/a[contains(@href,"B000AUIFCA")]]
//span[@class="zg_rankNumber"]
```

The XPath first find *'zg_itemImmersion' `div`* that contains the target text 'ASIN : B000AUIFCA'. Then from such `div`, *'zg_rankNumber' `span`* is returned.

Comment: That was awesome, why didn't the "." character sticking to the current element came to my Mind :( . Yes  ('//div[@class="zg_itemImmersion"][.//div[@class="zg_itemImageImmersion"]/a[contains(@href,"B000AUIFCA")]]//span[@class="zg_rankNumber"]/text()') does returns "10." Thanks @har07

Comment: I am also curious to know , is it something can be done using - preceeding-sibling also ?

Comment: Yes, if `preceeding-sibling` is used correctly. Note carefully that `preceding-sibling` only considers *siblings*, that is nodes that shares the same parent element f.e 'zg_rankDiv' is preceding sibling of 'zg_itemWrapper'. For elements with different parent try using just `preceding` axis.